# Converting Lotus Macros Into Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am in a process of rewriting a lotus program to excel 2010. I have the following code in lotus:

```
CLCMAT1
{WINDOWSOFF}
{BREAKOFF}
{SET "MACRO-TRACE";"OFF"}
{SELECT B:D1810..B:H1810;B:D1810}
{EDIT-CLEAR B:D1810..B:H1810;"CONTENTS"}
{SELECT B:J1810}
{CELL-ENTER "+D:L5"}
{CALC}
{SELECT B:F1810}
{CELL-ENTER "'4 Year Average Efficiency:"}
{SELECT B:O1810}
{CELL-ENTER "'4Yr"}
{SELECT B:j1810}
{SELECT-APPEND B:P1822..B:R1822;B:P1822}
{SELECT-APPEND B:P1819..B:R1819;B:P1819}
{SCROLL-TO-CELL B:G1809}
{CALC}
{WINDOWSON}
{QUIT}
```

Could someone suggest the equivalent in excel VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://www.acctadv.com/download/123toxl.doc): its a document which maps LOTUS 123 to Excel. It looks like its just what you need!

Comment: Hi thank you very very much only one question what "{SET "MACRO-TRACE";"OFF"} mean ? I could not find that in the document you sent to my attention

Comment: At a guess, it turns off some form of tracing. It should be safe to ignore.